# Output the results of a cmd line to an image file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I've already managed to output the results of a command line batch call to a text file, but I was wondering if it was possible to either convert this into an image file or to save it originally as an image file.

Comment: Once, take a screenshot.  Many times, print the output via a print-to-pdf printer, and then use Imagemagick to convert the pdf to the format you want

Comment: You should be able to use Imagemagick to convert the text file to an image file.

Comment: Can you please give more details? If the image is in binary format simple renaming of the file should work. Or you want to extract binary data from a binary file? What command line have you used?

Comment: After a batch script is run through the command line, the resultant output can be written to a text file. I'd like to convert this text file to an image file. Renaming doesn't work. Or I'd like to create an image directly

Answer (score 1):

You may use the convert function of **ImageMagick**.

You don't specify an OS. To install it on CentOS: `sudo yum install ImageMagick`

This package will provide the **convert** function.

Exemple:

`yourscript.sh > output.txt`

`convert output.txt output.png`

Comment: He does specify the OS indirectly.  Hover your mouse over the tags he used.

Comment: Please don't assume that I am a man. Please could you use the gender neutral OP or the actual gender neutral word "they". The programming community is already highly male dominated and using this language only increases isolation of the women in programming.